# Compute average number of days between dates in 2 columns based on rows in a 3rd column

Tags: r

I would like to compute the average number of days between Failure Date and Credit Date based on Product.  Just computing the number of days is no problem, but I can't find any examples of how to find the average number of days.

```
Product         Credit Date Failure Date
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/24/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/29/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/30/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/31/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/8/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/17/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/8/2019 0:00
Product1    2/1/2019 0:00   1/21/2019 0:00
Product2    2/1/2019 0:00   1/31/2019 0:00
Product2    2/1/2019 0:00   1/7/2019 0:00
Product2    2/1/2019 0:00   1/4/2019 0:00
Product2    2/1/2019 0:00   1/18/2019 0:00
Product2    2/1/2019 0:00   10/17/2018 0:00
```

Unfortunately I can't really think of a starting place so I don't have any code to share.  Anything would be fine, dplyr or whatever.  Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: With `dplyr`, you can do `df %>%
 group_by(Product) %>%
 summarise(Res = mean(Failure_Date - Credit_Date))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk Actually, it's the other way around, `mean(Credit_Date - Failure_Date)`. Care to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmfmnk & Rui Barradas got me where I needed to go.  For anyone interested I also added a handy unixtime conversion.

```
df$Credit_Date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$Credit_Date, origin="1970-01-01"))

df$Failure_Date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$Failure_Date, origin="1970-01-01"))

df %>% group_by(Product) %>% summarise(Res = mean(Credit_Date - Failure_Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.table approach

**sample data**

```
DT <- fread("Product         Credit_Date Failure_Date
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/24/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/29/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/30/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/31/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/8/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/17/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/8/2019T0:00
Product1    2/1/2019T0:00   1/21/2019T0:00
Product2    2/1/2019T0:00   1/31/2019T0:00
Product2    2/1/2019T0:00   1/7/2019T0:00
Product2    2/1/2019T0:00   1/4/2019T0:00
Product2    2/1/2019T0:00   1/18/2019T0:00
Product2    2/1/2019T0:00   10/17/2018T0:00")

#make real datetimes
cols = c("Credit_Date", "Failure_Date")
DT[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, as.POSIXct, format = "%m/%d/%YT%H:%M"), .SDcols = cols]
```

**code**

```
#summarise
DT[, .( mean = mean( difftime( Credit_Date, Failure_Date, units = "days" ) ) ), 
   by = Product ]
```

**output**

```
    Product          mean
1: Product1 11.00000 days
2: Product2 35.00833 days
```